# Create Carousel using nuxt3 vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to create a carousel with NUXT3 and VueJS and nuxt-swiper. However, I have been trying to do it but nothing works... I would like to know what my error(s) is(are) and if someone could help me in this task ?

I first did

```
pnpm install nuxt-swiper
```

Next, I added nuxt-swiper in the nuxt.config.js file

```
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtModule } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['nuxt-swiper']
  swiper: {
    // Swiper options
    //----------------------
    // prefix: 'Swiper',
    // styleLang: 'css',
    // modules: ['navigation', 'pagination'], // all modules are imported by default
  }
})
```

Next, I added this in my Component Vue

```
<template>
    <swiper :navigation="true" :modules="modules" class="mySwiper">
      <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
  </template>
```

After doing all this, the carousel does not work and nothing is displayed, I would like to know why?

Thank you in advance!